# Replacing two strings using awk

Tags: awk, gawk

I want to replace `@@` with `^` and `¤¤` with a newline in a file. To do this I wrote the code below, but it feels like there is a more elegant solution then calling gawk twice. Can anyone tell me if there is one?

```
cat test.txt | gawk '{ gsub("@@", "^"); print }' | gawk '{ gsub("¤¤", "\r\n"); print }'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, skin away the `cat`. Its useless except for file concatenation, which is its purpose. your `awk` command would be

```
awk '{gsub("@@","^");gsub("¤¤","\r\n");print}' file
```

If you want to remove all line breaks before doing the above

```
tr -d '\r\n' <file > temp && mv temp file
```

Comment: What if I want to also remove all line breaks BEFORE doing all of the substitutions above?

Answer (score 2):

Just call gsub() twice before printing.

gawk '{ gsub("@@", "^"); gsub("¤¤", "\r\n"); print }'