# awk - A single f==2 file number to replace two strings in the same file using second and third line of another file

Tags: string, awk, replace, output

I'm reading about `sub()` here in this [AWK User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions).

I would like to replace two strings in `dog.txt`, `cat` and `sun`, both respectively using the content of the second and third line of the `anti-dog-sun.txt` file.

**dog.txt:**

```
school
dog
sun
```

**anti-dog-sun.txt:**

```
house
cat
moon
```

First I would like to submit how I can replace the string `dog` of `dog.txt` using the second line of `anti-dog-sun.txt`, ie, replace `dog` with `cat` on the `dog.txt` and save output to `2.txt`, as follows below:

**code_0:**

```
awk \
'FNR==1 {++f}
f==1 {a[i++]=$0}
f==2 {if (sub(/dog/,a[int((h++)%(0.5*2)/1)+1])) ; print > "1.txt"}' \
anti-dog-sun.txt dog.txt
```

**output 1.txt:**

```
school
cat
sun
```

Now to be able to replace the string `sun` of `dog.txt` by using the third line of `anti-dog-sun.txt`,ie replace `sun` with `moon`, and save output to `2.txt`, I used the following:

**code_01:**

```
  awk \
  'FNR==1 {++f}
  f==1 {a[i++]=$0}
  f==2 {if (sub(/sun/,a[int((h++)%(0.5*2)/1)+2 ])) ; print > "2.txt"}' \
  anti-dog-sun.txt dog.txt
```

**output 2.txt:**

```
school
dog
moon
```

But I would not like to make these *two replacements* and save at `1.txt` and `2.txt` separately.

I would like to make the *two replacements* in a *single process* `f==2 {if(sub(); print > "single.txt"}`, ie *save only* in `single.txt`, where `single.txt` at the end would like this:

```
school
cat
moon
```

I tried somehow `..sub(/dog//sun/,a[int((h++)%(0.5*2)/1)+1],a[int((j++)%(0.5*2)/1)+2])..` to join the **code_0** and **code_01** in only **code_02** below:

```
awk \
'FNR==1 {++f}
f==1 {a[i++]=$0}
f==2 {if (sub(/dog/,/sun/,a[int((h++)%(0.5*2)/1)+1],a[int((j++)%(0.5*2)/1)+2])) ; print > "single.txt"}' \
anti-dog-sun.txt dog.txt
```

But get follow error:

```
awk: cmd. line:3: f==2 {if (sub(/dog/,/sun/,a[int((h++)%(0.5*2)/1)+1],a[int((j++)%(0.5*2)/1)+2])) ; print > "single.txt"}
awk: cmd. line:3:                                                                              ^ 4 is invalid as number of arguments for sub
```

**Note:** Before posting this question I read the guide *AWK User Guide* several times and I also tried to seek some answer here in the OS or out of it, and I'm not sure if it is possible to make these two replacements using only a `sub()`.

**EDIT UPDATE:** If you really can not perform the 2 replacements using `sub()` once time is there any way to do this *without writing more than once* in the `single.txt` file? A solution that is portable? *An answer that satisfies my edit **UPDATE 02**.*

**EDIT UPDATE 01:** I do not want to simply replace the second and third line of `dog.txt` respectively using the second and third line of `anti-dog-sun.txt` (this is only to display an MWE), if the solution should look for the strings `dog` and `sun`.

**EDIT UPDATE 02:** Another condition is that the mechanism  `a[int((k++)%(x3*2)/x2)+x1]`  should be maintained because this MWE emerged from a real use of the answer of this issue here [awk - Replace each X nth occurs from anything between two strings in Different files using line range from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69906828/awk-replace-each-x-nth-occurs-from-anything-between-two-strings-in-different-f/69922307#69922307).

**EDIT UPDATE 03:** There was a typing error while I made edits of my question I already corrected `dog.txt anti-dog-sun.txt` to `anti-dog-sun.txt dog.txt`. Sorry.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your problem well. say you have two files, both files have the same number of lines (say 3). So you want the 2nd & 3rd line in file1 to be replaced by the corresponding lines in file2?

Comment: well.... you should really click the "Add comment" button after you finished the "but....." part..  I don't get the rule. sorry. Good luck.

Comment: @Kent To your first comment: In case of my question this is what happens but what I want is to look for a string and then replace for a certain nth line anti-dog-sun.txt line, and also do this for another string1 and replace for certain nth-1 anti-dog-sun.txt line.

Comment: My keyboard locked, I can not format the codes in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
awk \
'FNR==1 {++f}
f==1 {a[i++]=$0}
f==2 {sub(/dog/,a[int((h++)%(0.5*2)/1)+1]); sub(/sun/,a[int((j++)%(0.5*2)/1)+2]) ; print > "single.txt"}' \
anti-dog-sun.txt dog.txt
```

**single.txt:**

```
school
cat
moon
```

delete `if`, put each substitution in a single `sub()`,  separate each `sub()` by `;` and then print `single.txt`.

Related: [Replacing two strings using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829247/replacing-two-strings-using-awk).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to perform the replacement based of the contents, would you please try:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[FNR]=$0; next}          # store the lines of anti-dog-sun.txt in the array "a"
    /dog|sun/ {$0=a[FNR]} 1             # replace the lines of dog.txt if the keyword matches
' anti-dog-sun.txt dog.txt
```

Comment: I will test your response, but I am responding here the answer to User Kent's comment: To your first comment: In case of my question this is what happens but what I want is to look for a string and then replace for a certain nth line anti-dog-sun.txt line, and also do this for another string1 and replace for certain nth-1 anti-dog-sun.txt line.

Comment: about your comment on answer: Assuming you want to perform the replacement regardless of the contents, would you please try: . Then depends on rather to find the string dog and the string  sun. My keyboard locked, I can not format the codes in the comments.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Does it meet your requirements?

Comment: I am reviewing my issue looking for typing or code exchange errors, since I make sure this signal your response as useful or resolved.  Another condition is that the mechanism  a[int((k++)%(x3*2)/x2)+x1]  should be maintained because this MWE emerged from a real use of the answer of this issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69906828/awk-replace-each-x-nth-occurs-from-anything-between-two-strings-in-different-f/69922307#69922307

Comment: If you know your own additional condition, you can modify my code accordingly. What is your problem?

Comment: I need to try first adapt your response and know if I can carry the mechanism a[int((k++)% (x3*2)/x2)+x1] into it.

Comment: It will help us understand your requirements and problem well if you can elaborate your input file and expected result extending current dog/cat example, instead of just putting the formula or linking to another post. Cheers.

Comment: I am trying to understand your difficulty, because I have already posted an MWE containing the expected input (anti-dog-sun.txt) and the expected single.txt output in my question, but since the solution presented maintains the mechanism quoted.

Comment: There was a typing error while I made edits of my question I already corrected `dog.txt anti-dog-sun.txt` to `anti-dog-sun.txt dog.txt`. Sorry.

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm trying to adapt your response to contain the mechanism I mentioned, if I can give your response as solved, if no further response already arises with this adaptation made and proven. I need some time..

Comment: I tried something like this:  awk \ 'FNR==1 {++f} f==1 {a[i++]=$0} f==2 {if (sub(/dog|sun/,a[int((h++)%(0.5*2)/1)+1]|| a[int((j++)%(0.5*2)/1)+1])) ; print > "single.txt"}' \ anti-dog-sun.txt dog.txt    but it results in syntaxe error.   My keyboard locked, I can not format the codes in the comments.

Comment: also i tried awk \ 'FNR==1 {++f} f==1 {a[i++]=$0} f==2 {if (sub(/dog|sun/,""a[int((h++)%(0.5*2)/1)+1]""a[int((j++)%(0.5*2)/1)+1]"")) ; print > "single.txt"}' \ anti-dog-sun.txt dog.txt

Comment: Please, explain what you want to do in English, not with the magic formula `a[int((j++)%(0.5*2)/1)+1]`. IMHO the operation `int((j++)%(0.5*2)/1)` looks meaningless (no more or no less than `j++`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use head and tail:

```
head -n1 dog.txt; tail -n2 anti-dog.txt
school
cat
moon
```

Or with awk:

```
awk '(FNR==NR && NR==1) || (NR>FNR && FNR>1)' dog.txt anti-dog.txt
# same
```

Comment: Read my edit uptate 02 Please. thank you for helping, I believe this question may need broken in parts.